# InsertAttachment withAlternateFilename is not working in iOS 10

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, imessage, ios-messages-extension

As per doc:

```
@method     insertAttachment:withAlternateFilename:completionHandler:
@abstract   The NSURL instance provided in the URL parameter is inserted into the Messages.app
input field. This must be a file URL.
@param      URL                The URL to the media file to be inserted.
@param      filename           If you supply a string here, the message UI uses it for the attachment. Use an alternate filename to better describe the attachment or to make the name more readable.
@param      completionHandler  A completion handler called when the insert is complete.
 */
open func insertAttachment(_ URL: URL, withAlternateFilename filename: String?, completionHandler: (@escaping (Error?) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

Where it says for

> filename ---> If you supply a string here, the message UI uses it for
>   the attachment. Use an alternate filename to better describe the
>   attachment or to make the name more readable.

And my code is:

```
if let conversation = activeConversation {
    conversation.insertAttachment(fileURL, withAlternateFilename: "This is file Description.", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

But it is not showing anywhere in message app.

I am sending video file here.

I want to show that description on navigation bar title when user click on message or below the `MSMessage` if possible.

Comment: Try to specify file's extension when setting alternate filename, for example: "This is file Description.png"

Comment: Thanks for the comment but It doesn't help. @azimov

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am running across the same issue!

Comment: 2019, and still a bug.

Comment: The Swift version of this is broken. The objective-C version of this works as expected. Have to import Objective-C .h and .m file and supply a bridging header to your Swift project. Works great and the filename is correct

Comment: FYI: this also affects the `sendAttachment(_:withAlternateFilename:completionHandler:)`, so there is not any workarounds in the API. I see this on Xcode 11.3.1.

Comment: I see this working in Xcode 12.1 and in iOS 14. I don't know where it was fixed (Xcode vs. iOS).

Answer (score 0):

As of WWWDC 2020, I think this was fixed via Xcode 12 or iOS 14, because I saw it in Xcode 11, but my updated builds work.

Answer (score -4):

As per latest doc, try 
`func addAttachmentURL(_ attachmentURL: NSURL,
withAlternateFilename alternateFilename: String?) -> Bool`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMessageComposeViewController/addAttachmentURL:withAlternateFilename:

Comment: FYI: That isn't just the wrong class documentation, that's the wrong `framework` (in case you were wondering why you got so many downvotes, thats my guess).